# Call PHP API with JWT authentication

Tags: php, jwt

I am calling a PHP script with curl API and PHP script return the data in JSON format, I want to use token-based authentication. After a lot of R&D, I found that I can use Firebase JWT authentication.

My curl script is below:

```
    $url  = "http://localhost/module/returndata.php";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
```

and I have a PHP script file(returndata.php) which is return data. Now I want to JWT-Authentication when I called this file. Please suggest me if anyone have an idea regarding it.

Currently, I got some links and created a test file but I don't have an idea how to do it.

```
<?php
            ini_set("display_errors", "1");
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            set_time_limit(0);

            require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
            use \Firebase\JWT\JWT; 
            define('SECRET_KEY','Admin%^&ttt') ; // secret key can be a random string  and keep in secret from anyone
            define('ALGORITHM','HS512');



                $tokenId    = base64_encode(random_bytes(32));
                $issuedAt   = time();
                $notBefore  = $issuedAt + 10;  //Adding 10 seconds
                $expire     = $notBefore + 7200; // Adding 60 seconds
                $serverName = 'http://localhost/'; /// set your domain name 


                /*
                 * Create the token as an array
                 */
                $data = [
                    'iat'  => $issuedAt,         // Issued at: time when the token was generated
                    'jti'  => $tokenId,          // Json Token Id: an unique identifier for the token
                    'iss'  => $serverName,       // Issuer
                    'nbf'  => $notBefore,        // Not before
                    'exp'  => $expire,           // Expire
                    'data' => [                  // Data related to the logged user you can set your required data
                 'id'   => "smithjames", // id from the users table
                 'name' => "admin", //  name
                              ]
                ];
              $secretKey = base64_decode(SECRET_KEY);
              /// Here we will transform this array into JWT:
              $jwt = JWT::encode(
                        $data, //Data to be encoded in the JWT
                        $secretKey, // The signing key
                         ALGORITHM 
                       ); 
             $unencodedArray = ['jwt' => $jwt];





             try {
           $secretKey = base64_decode(SECRET_KEY); 
           $DecodedDataArray = JWT::decode($_REQUEST['tokVal'], $secretKey, array(ALGORITHM));

           echo  "{'status' : 'success' ,'data':".json_encode($DecodedDataArray)." }";die();

           } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "{'status' : 'fail' ,'msg':'Unauthorized'}";die();
           }
```

I have already installed "Firebase\JWT\JWT" and working fine but how to implement it.

Comment: Do you want to return the Auth Key in header? Or please explain what you are expecting?

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA,I want to call my php script with curl using JWT.So what I needed to do this.I have already installed JWT.

Answer (score 1):

You need fisrt get login request and take JWT token key to store in cookie or localstorage for next requests with specified header auth. like "Bearer" to confirm stored token is correct or not.

Comment: ,Plese explain with example so that I can implement same.